# Just cannot get the tikz scaling right in a subfigure environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, subfloats, tikzscale

I understand how to scale a single tikz picture either by `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = ]` or `\resizebox` or `\scalebox`. However, this seems to collapse once I put them into a subfigure environment. This is how the tikz picture looks like standing alone:

[image]

But this is what it looks like in subfigures (first panel):

[image]

First the whole picture is too small. But once I scale it up with a `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, every node/.style={scale=0.5}]`, it results in panel (b) where the lines are too thick and the dashed lines are so spaced out. What I want is just a scaled version of the standalone figure -- how do I do that?

Here is my (not so minimal) WE:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
  \centering
  \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
    \begin{axis}[
      xlabel={$\Pr(\theta=1)$},
      ylabel={$U$},
      xmin=-0.1, xmax=1,
      axis lines=middle,
      samples=100,
      width=0.6\textwidth,
      xtick=\empty,
      ytick=\empty,
      xlabel style={anchor=west},
      ylabel style={anchor=east},
      clip=false,
      ]
      \addplot[black, thick, domain=0.75:1] {x};
      \addplot[black, dashed, domain=0:0.75] {x};
      \addplot[black, thick, domain=0:0.75] {1 - x};
      \addplot[black, dashed, domain=0.75:1] {1 - x};

      
      % Intersection points
      \coordinate (A) at (0.5, 0.5);
      \coordinate (B) at (0.75, 0.75);
      \coordinate (C) at (0.5, 0);
      \coordinate (D) at (0.75, 0);
      \coordinate (D1) at (0.75, 0);
      \coordinate (E1) at (0.65, 0);
      \coordinate (F1) at (0.85, 0);
      \coordinate (E2) at (0.65,0.35);
      \coordinate (F2) at (0.85,0.85);
      \coordinate (MEAN2) at (0.8,0.8);
      \coordinate (MEAN1) at (0.8,0.74);

      % Point indicators
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=black] at (C) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=black] at (D) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=none] at (E1) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=none] at (F1) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=red] at (E2) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=red] at (F2) {};
      \draw[thick, red, dashed] (E2) -- (F2);
      \node[draw,diamond,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=red] at (MEAN1) {};
      \node[draw,diamond,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=black] at (MEAN2) {};

      % Dashed line and label
      \node[below left] at (0, 0) {$0$};
      \node[below] at (1, 0) {1};
      \draw[dashed] (A) -- (0.5, 0);
      \node[below right] at (0.5, 0) {$\bar{\mu}_P$};
      \draw[dashed] (B) -- (0.75, 0);
      \node[below right] at (0.75, 0) {$\bar{\mu}_A$};
      \node[below right] at (E1) {$\mu_{10}$};
      \node[below right] at (F1) {$\mu_{11}$};
      \draw[dashed] (MEAN2) -- (0.8,0);

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \caption[]{{\small Ex1}}    
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
  \centering 
  \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, every node/.style={scale=0.5}]
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
    \begin{axis}[
      xlabel={$\Pr(\theta=1)$},
      ylabel={$U$},
      xmin=-0.1, xmax=1,
      axis lines=middle,
      samples=100,
      width=0.6\textwidth,
      xtick=\empty,
      ytick=\empty,
      xlabel style={anchor=west},
      ylabel style={anchor=east},
      clip=false,
      ]
      \addplot[black, thick, domain=0.75:1] {x};
      \addplot[black, dashed, domain=0:0.75] {x};
      \addplot[black, thick, domain=0:0.75] {1 - x};
      \addplot[black, dashed, domain=0.75:1] {1 - x};

      
      % Intersection points
      \coordinate (A) at (0.5, 0.5);
      \coordinate (B) at (0.75, 0.75);
      \coordinate (C) at (0.5, 0);
      \coordinate (D) at (0.75, 0);
      \coordinate (D1) at (0.75, 0);
      \coordinate (E1) at (0.7, 0);
      \coordinate (F1) at (0.45, 0);
      \coordinate (E2) at (0.7,0.3);
      \coordinate (F2) at (0.45,0.55);
      \coordinate (MEAN1) at (0.6,0.4);
      \coordinate (MEAN2) at (0.6,0.6);

      % Point indicators
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=black] at (C) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=black] at (D) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=none] at (E1) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=none] at (F1) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=red] at (E2) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=red] at (F2) {};
      \draw[thick, red, dashed] (E2) -- (F2);
      \node[draw,diamond,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=red] at (MEAN1) {};
      \node[draw,diamond,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=black] at (MEAN2) {};

      % Dashed line and label
      \node[below left] at (0, 0) {$0$};
      \node[below] at (1, 0) {1};
      \draw[dashed] (A) -- (0.5, 0);
      %\node[below right] at (0.5, 0) {$\bar{\mu}_P$};
      \draw[dashed] (B) -- (0.75, 0);
      %\node[below right] at (0.75, 0) {$\bar{\mu}_A$};
      \node[below] at (E1) {$\mu_{11}$};
      \node[below] at (F1) {$\mu_{10}$};
      \draw[dashed] (MEAN2) -- (0.6, 0);
      \node[below] at (0.6, 0) {$\mu_1$};

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \caption[]{{\small Ex2}}    
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: PGFPlots makes this a bit more complicated since it does its own scaling. I don't really see the need for it either, this can be easily done in plain TikZ and might be easier to scale then.

Comment: You may need to add `transform shape`. See example at the end of ch. 17.5.1 (Positioning nodes) in the pgfmanual

Comment: Note that subfigure (like minipage) changes the value of \textwidth etc.  I would avoid using things like \textwidth in a tikzpicture anyway and use tikz own scaling features.

Comment: Please provide complete enough code, which compiles, next time. Nobody likes to reengineer preamble for incomplete code. Thank you

Comment: @MS-SPO My apologies for not providing the preamble. It is very long with other packages for the paper and math, and I am not entirely sure which of the packages are required for this MWE. I will spent some time to figure this out before I post next time - thanks for the reminder!

Comment: That‘s easy to do: a) remove all packages, e.g. by commenting-out, b) compile, which will fail, c) guided by the first error messages or warnings add individual packages until it compiles, d) check, if really all are needed (repeat this process).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an other way to do it, using `subfiles`. This package allows you to:

- compile sub-files with the `preamble` of your main-document
- compile the whole main-document
- which moves some of the scaling action into the sub-files.

**Advantage** for workflow:

- be consistent with preambles (there's only one)
- compile sub-files separately, e.g. during developmenet
- compile everything together whenever needed
- i.e. check `fig1.pdf` and `fig2.pdf` first, finally generate `main.pdf`

Let's see, how it works.

#### main.tex

Easy-peasy, isn't it? Just provide all packages here, which your sub-files need. E.g. one could need just `Tikz`, another just `graphicx` and so on ... and all appear here.

[image: main]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}%  probably your preferred class
\usepackage{subfiles}%                  allows joint and individual compiles
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfigure}%                 your troublemaker

\begin{document}

 \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfigure[Ex1]{\subfile{fig1}}%    <<< new
    \subfigure[Ex2]{\subfile{fig2}}

    \caption{Whatever you want }
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

#### fig1.tex

Important differences to the approach via separate pdf-compiles included as images, [see above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/693715/245790):

- now compiles as class `article`
- requires `[scale=0.65, transform shape]% <<< new`, see pgfmanual
- do fine-tuning for width here
- option `width` instead may work, too, somehow ...

[image: fig1]

```
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}% = reuse preamble found in main.tex

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65, transform shape]% <<< new
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
    \begin{axis}[
      xlabel={$\Pr(\theta=1)$},
      ylabel={$U$},
      xmin=-0.1, xmax=1,
      axis lines=middle,
      samples=100,
%      width=0.6\textwidth,
      xtick=\empty,
      ytick=\empty,
      xlabel style={anchor=west},
      ylabel style={anchor=east},
      clip=false,
      ]
      \addplot[black, thick, domain=0.75:1] {x};
      \addplot[black, dashed, domain=0:0.75] {x};
      \addplot[black, thick, domain=0:0.75] {1 - x};
      \addplot[black, dashed, domain=0.75:1] {1 - x};
      
      % Intersection points
      \coordinate (A)       at (0.5 , 0.5);
      \coordinate (B)       at (0.75, 0.75);
      \coordinate (C)       at (0.5 , 0);
      \coordinate (D)       at (0.75, 0);
      \coordinate (D1)      at (0.75, 0);
      \coordinate (E1)      at (0.65, 0);
      \coordinate (F1)      at (0.85, 0);
      \coordinate (E2)      at (0.65, 0.35);
      \coordinate (F2)      at (0.85, 0.85);
      \coordinate (MEAN2)   at (0.8 , 0.8);
      \coordinate (MEAN1)   at (0.8 , 0.74);

      % Point indicators
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=black] at (C) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=black] at (D) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=none] at (E1) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=none] at (F1) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=red] at (E2) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=red] at (F2) {};
      \draw[thick, red, dashed] (E2) -- (F2);
      \node[draw,diamond,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=red] at (MEAN1) {};
      \node[draw,diamond,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=black] at (MEAN2) {};

      % Dashed line and label
      \node[below left] at (0, 0) {$0$};
      \node[below] at (1, 0) {1};
      \draw[dashed] (A) -- (0.5, 0);
      \node[below right] at (0.5, 0) {$\bar{\mu}_P$};
      \draw[dashed] (B) -- (0.75, 0);
      \node[below right] at (0.75, 0) {$\bar{\mu}_A$};
      \node[below right] at (E1) {$\mu_{10}$};
      \node[below right] at (F1) {$\mu_{11}$};
      \draw[dashed] (MEAN2) -- (0.8,0);
      
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### fig2.tex

Same as with fig1.tex .

[image: fig2]

```
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}% = reuse preamble found in main.tex

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape,scale=0.65]% <<< new
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
    \begin{axis}[
      xlabel={$\Pr(\theta=1)$},
      ylabel={$U$},
      xmin=-0.1, xmax=1,
      axis lines=middle,
      samples=100,
%      width=0.6\textwidth,
      xtick=\empty,
      ytick=\empty,
      xlabel style={anchor=west},
      ylabel style={anchor=east},
      clip=false,
      ]
      \addplot[black, thick, domain=0.75:1] {x};
      \addplot[black, dashed, domain=0:0.75] {x};
      \addplot[black, thick, domain=0:0.75] {1 - x};
      \addplot[black, dashed, domain=0.75:1] {1 - x};

      
      % Intersection points
      \coordinate (A) at (0.5, 0.5);
      \coordinate (B) at (0.75, 0.75);
      \coordinate (C) at (0.5, 0);
      \coordinate (D) at (0.75, 0);
      \coordinate (D1) at (0.75, 0);
      \coordinate (E1) at (0.7, 0);
      \coordinate (F1) at (0.45, 0);
      \coordinate (E2) at (0.7,0.3);
      \coordinate (F2) at (0.45,0.55);
      \coordinate (MEAN1) at (0.6,0.4);
      \coordinate (MEAN2) at (0.6,0.6);

      % Point indicators
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=black] at (C) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=black] at (D) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=none] at (E1) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=none] at (F1) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=red] at (E2) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=red] at (F2) {};
      \draw[thick, red, dashed] (E2) -- (F2);
      \node[draw,diamond,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=red] at (MEAN1) {};
      \node[draw,diamond,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=black] at (MEAN2) {};

      % Dashed line and label
      \node[below left] at (0, 0) {$0$};
      \node[below] at (1, 0) {1};
      \draw[dashed] (A) -- (0.5, 0);
      %\node[below right] at (0.5, 0) {$\bar{\mu}_P$};
      \draw[dashed] (B) -- (0.75, 0);
      %\node[below right] at (0.75, 0) {$\bar{\mu}_A$};
      \node[below] at (E1) {$\mu_{11}$};
      \node[below] at (F1) {$\mu_{10}$};
      \draw[dashed] (MEAN2) -- (0.6, 0);
      \node[below] at (0.6, 0) {$\mu_1$};

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the two very detailed answers! Can I please ask if the final presentation of the graphs will be different in these two approaches? From my understanding the first approach is similar to compile a pdf, screenshot the pdf, and then attach the screenshot to the main file. Will it result in resolution loss when zooming in or printing on paper? Does the second approach prevent this problem?

Comment: It‘s not a screenshot, more like an input. Here, Tikz is vectorgraphics, so pdf is vectorgraphic. Try zooming in. // It‘s different, when you compile a bitmap into a pdf: that will be a bitmap in pdf-syntax, with pixelation etc.  // subfile is for convenience: it doesn‘t require precompiled sub-files.

Answer (score 0):

I suggests using a different approach:

- create two separate files with `Tikz`/`pgfplots`, `fig1.tex` and `fig2.tex`
- compile them to `pdf`
- include them as `graphicx` in `main.tex`

#### main.tex

Code shows two ways to `includegraphics`.

[image: main]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \subfigure[Ex1]{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{fig1}}
    \subfigure[Ex2]{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{fig2}}
    \caption{Whatever you want \dots one way to do it}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \subfigure[Ex1]{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{fig1}}
    \subfigure[Ex2]{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{fig2}}

    \caption{Whatever you want \dots an other way to do it}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

#### fig1.tex

No width-spec. Class `standalone`

[image: fig1]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
    \begin{axis}[
      xlabel={$\Pr(\theta=1)$},
      ylabel={$U$},
      xmin=-0.1, xmax=1,
      axis lines=middle,
      samples=100,
%      width=0.6\textwidth,
      xtick=\empty,
      ytick=\empty,
      xlabel style={anchor=west},
      ylabel style={anchor=east},
      clip=false,
      ]
      \addplot[black, thick, domain=0.75:1] {x};
      \addplot[black, dashed, domain=0:0.75] {x};
      \addplot[black, thick, domain=0:0.75] {1 - x};
      \addplot[black, dashed, domain=0.75:1] {1 - x};
      
      % Intersection points
      \coordinate (A)       at (0.5 , 0.5);
      \coordinate (B)       at (0.75, 0.75);
      \coordinate (C)       at (0.5 , 0);
      \coordinate (D)       at (0.75, 0);
      \coordinate (D1)      at (0.75, 0);
      \coordinate (E1)      at (0.65, 0);
      \coordinate (F1)      at (0.85, 0);
      \coordinate (E2)      at (0.65, 0.35);
      \coordinate (F2)      at (0.85, 0.85);
      \coordinate (MEAN2)   at (0.8 , 0.8);
      \coordinate (MEAN1)   at (0.8 , 0.74);

      % Point indicators
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=black] at (C) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=black] at (D) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=none] at (E1) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=none] at (F1) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=red] at (E2) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=red] at (F2) {};
      \draw[thick, red, dashed] (E2) -- (F2);
      \node[draw,diamond,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=red] at (MEAN1) {};
      \node[draw,diamond,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=black] at (MEAN2) {};

      % Dashed line and label
      \node[below left] at (0, 0) {$0$};
      \node[below] at (1, 0) {1};
      \draw[dashed] (A) -- (0.5, 0);
      \node[below right] at (0.5, 0) {$\bar{\mu}_P$};
      \draw[dashed] (B) -- (0.75, 0);
      \node[below right] at (0.75, 0) {$\bar{\mu}_A$};
      \node[below right] at (E1) {$\mu_{10}$};
      \node[below right] at (F1) {$\mu_{11}$};
      \draw[dashed] (MEAN2) -- (0.8,0);
      
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### fig2.tex

No width-spec. Class `standalone`

[image: fig2]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=2, every node/.style={scale=0.5}]
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
    \begin{axis}[
      xlabel={$\Pr(\theta=1)$},
      ylabel={$U$},
      xmin=-0.1, xmax=1,
      axis lines=middle,
      samples=100,
%      width=0.6\textwidth,
      xtick=\empty,
      ytick=\empty,
      xlabel style={anchor=west},
      ylabel style={anchor=east},
      clip=false,
      ]
      \addplot[black, thick, domain=0.75:1] {x};
      \addplot[black, dashed, domain=0:0.75] {x};
      \addplot[black, thick, domain=0:0.75] {1 - x};
      \addplot[black, dashed, domain=0.75:1] {1 - x};

      
      % Intersection points
      \coordinate (A) at (0.5, 0.5);
      \coordinate (B) at (0.75, 0.75);
      \coordinate (C) at (0.5, 0);
      \coordinate (D) at (0.75, 0);
      \coordinate (D1) at (0.75, 0);
      \coordinate (E1) at (0.7, 0);
      \coordinate (F1) at (0.45, 0);
      \coordinate (E2) at (0.7,0.3);
      \coordinate (F2) at (0.45,0.55);
      \coordinate (MEAN1) at (0.6,0.4);
      \coordinate (MEAN2) at (0.6,0.6);

      % Point indicators
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=black] at (C) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=black] at (D) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=none] at (E1) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=none] at (F1) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=red] at (E2) {};
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=red] at (F2) {};
      \draw[thick, red, dashed] (E2) -- (F2);
      \node[draw,diamond,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=red] at (MEAN1) {};
      \node[draw,diamond,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=black] at (MEAN2) {};

      % Dashed line and label
      \node[below left] at (0, 0) {$0$};
      \node[below] at (1, 0) {1};
      \draw[dashed] (A) -- (0.5, 0);
      %\node[below right] at (0.5, 0) {$\bar{\mu}_P$};
      \draw[dashed] (B) -- (0.75, 0);
      %\node[below right] at (0.75, 0) {$\bar{\mu}_A$};
      \node[below] at (E1) {$\mu_{11}$};
      \node[below] at (F1) {$\mu_{10}$};
      \draw[dashed] (MEAN2) -- (0.6, 0);
      \node[below] at (0.6, 0) {$\mu_1$};

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```